# Configure the host names (A record or CNAME) with slashes

Tags: azure, dns, hosting, cname, a-records

There are many projects in solution (ASP.NET MVC). They are published to Azure. For example,

1. mysite.azurewebsites.net
2. mysiteview.azurewebsites.net
3. mysitecustomers.azurewebsites.net
4. mysiteapi.azurewebsites.net

I want to connect it to my domain, purchased from GoDaddy, for example: "mydomain.com"
How to configure the host names (A record or CNAME) to get such links:

- mydomain.com - mysite.azurewebsites.net
- mydomain.com/view - mysiteview.azurewebsites.net
- mydomain.com/customers - mysitecustomers.azurewebsites.net
- mydomain.com/api - mysiteapi.azurewebsites.net

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of this problem is here:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2014/09/21/deploying-multiple-virtual-directories-to-a-single-azure-website/